# del vs delete()

Tags: django, object

```
class myClass (models.Model):
  related_operation = models.ForeignKey('self', null = True)

  __related_operation = None

  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    if self.related_operation != self.__related_operation:
      del self.__related_operation

    super(Operation, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
    self.__related_operation = self.related_operation
```

should I use del self.__related_operation or should I use self.__related_operation.delete()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del self.__related_operation` will attempt to delete the instance's `__related_operation` attribute. I'm not sure why you would want to do this.

If you want to remove the object from the database, use the `delete()` method.

Comment: I'm not sure what I want ;D As you can see, i need __related_operation only to check if it's changed.

Comment: I've tried to make my answer clearer, but if you don't know what you want then I can't really help you. Only you know whether you want to delete the related object from the database ;)

Comment: let me try to explain: i have field related_operation which i try to modify with formset. But when i change related_operation (make new one) i have to delete old related_operation. so i have to have a property to compare old with possible new - if differs - i have to remove old

Comment: Sorry, I can't really offer you any more advice. Hope you work it out :)

Comment: Yes, now I understand what is the difference ;D